# Как преобразовать строку в число с плавающей точкой?

Tags: javascript

Есть число: 1200.00

Парсю его:

```js
console.log(parseFloat('1200.00'))
```

но на выходе получается '1200'.
Как мне оставить нули в конце?

Comment: Начинаем. Чем отличаются числа `1200` и `1200.00`?

Comment: @igor есть товары с учетом копеек, где-то 20.00, где-то 20.45

Comment: Это ответ не на мой вопрос.

Comment: @igor 1200 целое число 1200.00 не целое

Comment: "1200" и "1200.00" - это два разных изображения одного и того же числа. Когда оба переведены в числа, эти два числа неотличимы с точки зрения компьютера и  пользователя. Не переводите строки в числа если хотите сохранить различия в записи. Скорее всего вы неудачно сформулировали задачу. Объясните житейским языком что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(parseFloat('1200.00').toFixed(2))
```

Comment: Можно проще: `console.log('1200.00');`

Comment: да...............

Comment: @Igor
Я лишь сократил пример, а вы посчитали его абсурдным.

Comment: А как же `console.log(parseFloat('1200').toFixed(2))`. Что-то мне говорит, что ТС захочет увидеть число без "лишних" нулей в этом случае.